# use F for referencing 2 tables to update python

Tags: python, mysql, django, performance, updatemodel

HI i have a script which use 2 or 3 tables for referencing to update the data in database

below is the code

```
getteam  = myteam.objects.only("id")  # [:2] limits the query to 2 just for testing
for i in getteam:
     gettraining = training.objects.get(teamID=i.id)    # because for now the traning table is empty

     getPrimary =  gettraining.primary
     if getPrimary  == 1 or getPrimary == 0 :
         getteamPlayers =  teamPlayers.objects.filter(teamId=i.id)
         for t in getteamPlayers :
             getmyplayer= myplayer.objects.get(id=t.playerId)
             getPlayerAge = getmyplayer.age     
             increase = max(0, (1+((MIDAGE - getPlayerAge) * MULTIPLIER) / 100) * 0.05 / 9)
             getvitals = vitals.objects.get(playerID=t.playerId)
             getvitals.velocity = min(max(getvitals.velocity + increase,0),1)  
             getvitals.power = min(max(getvitals.power + increase,0),1)  
             getvitals.arm = min(max(getvitals.arm + increase,0),1)  
             getvitals.ranges = min(max(getvitals.ranges + increase,0),1)  
             getvitals.save()
             print t.playerId
```

i am running this script on terminal and i want to use something like f class or update , because it takes so much time to update , can you please suggest how can i use or increase the speed of insertion time

Comment: Can you show the associated models please? I'm betting a significant speedup will occur simply by loading the models you need with `select_related()` with 1-3 queries, rather than 4 queries per team.

Answer (score 0):

A dramatic performance boost could be given running your update function in a single transaction.

Take a look at [Django database transaction management](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/) for details.
You could consider the use of [django.db.transaction.commit_on_success](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_on_success) that can be used as a context manager:

```
from django.db import transaction


with transaction.commit_on_success():
    # your code here
```

or as a function decorator:

```
from django.db import transaction


@transaction.commit_on_success
def update_function():
    # your code here
```

Comment: This isn't going to help. The existing code executes 4 queries per loop plus the save. That's what the bottleneck is.